# AngularJS change attribute values

Tags: html, angularjs

I have rows in table which generate buttons dynamically

```
    <tr ng-repeat="task in task">
    <td>{{task.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{task.Comments}}</td>
    <td>{{task.Project}}</td>
    <td>{{task.Duration}}</td>
    <td>
      <button class={{editable}} ng-click="editTask(task.id)"></button>
      <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

In my Angular code I have

```
$scope.editTask = function(id){
        if($scope.editable == "glyphicon glyphicon-edit"){
        $scope.editable="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save";
        }
        else{
            $scope.editable="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"
        }
    }
```

So basically I want to change the edit glyphicon to save glyphicon and the save glyphicon back to edit glyphicon. But since I have assigned class to the button it changes the glyphicons of all buttons in the table. How can I change the icon of only the button of which is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

You can update your HTML to

```
<td>
    <button class="glyphicon" ng-class="task.editable" ng-click="editTask(task)"></button>
    <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
</td>
```

Passing the task instead of the `id` directly allows you to update it's `editable` state directly on the `task`. Your controller should update the `editable` property

```
$scope.editTask = function(task){
    if(task.editable == "glyphicon-edit") {
       task.editable="glyphicon-floppy-save";
    }
    else{
       task.editable="glyphicon-edit"
    }
}
```

Note: I've passed the `glyphicon` class directly to the button since it won't change.

**Approach 2**

You could also approach it another way and keep the condition in the HTML

```
<button class="glyphicon" ng-class="task.editable ? 'glyphicon-edit': 'glyphicon-floppy-save'" ng-click="editTask(task)"></button>
```

And your controller could just update the `editable` property

```
$scope.editTask = function(task){
    task.editable = !task.editable;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By assigning the `editable` variable to the `task` object:

```
$scope.editTask = function(task){
    if(task.editable == "glyphicon glyphicon-trash")
        task.editable="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save";        
    else  
      task.editable="glyphicon glyphicon-trash";        
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<button ng-class="editable" ng-click="editTask(task)"></button>
```

This way, you'll end up having an unique class for each of your `task` object.

Also, remember to use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) instead of the plain `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `editable` property on the `task` itself and then use `task.editable`. This will be a unique property for each `task`

Answer (score 0):

you need to make some changes to your code. I'm gonna provide you the code I used in order to achieve what I believe is your goal, and will then explain the reasoning behind it.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
      <td>{{task.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{task.Comments}}</td>
      <td>{{task.Project}}</td>
      <td>{{task.Duration}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class={{task.editable}} ng-click="editTask($index)"></button>
        <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

As you can see, I included an attribute inside the task called *editable*. I'll be using this attribute to change the class. You'll also notice I', using `$index`. This is a default counter for `ng-repeat`.

```
$scope.tasks.push({Name: 'Jorge', Comments: 'Comentario',Project: 'Tengu', Duration: 45, editable: "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"});
$scope.tasks.push({Name: 'Mermelada', Comments: 'Comentario2',Project: 'DM-300', Duration: 30, editable: "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"});
```

You'll need to add the editable properties to your objects.

```
$scope.editTask = function(id){
      if($scope.tasks[id].editable == "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"){
        $scope.tasks[id].editable="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save";
      } else{
          $scope.tasks[id].editable="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
      }
    }
```

I don't believe this needs much explanation. Please let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to switch between class just use `ng-class`

exemple, you have a variable `leftOrRight`, we will assume that you have two class in you css file: `floatLeft` and `floatRight` (with the attribute `float: right/left;` )

```
ng-class="{ floatRight : leftOrRight == 'right', floatLeft : leftOrRight == 'left' }"
```

If you set leftOrRight to "right" you will have the same thing as `class="floatRight"` for exemple.